# MvvmCross iOS Two converters for one binding?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Any possibility to use more than one conversion for MvvmCross one binding?

For ex.:

```
this.CreateBinding(UIImage)
                .For(i => i.Image)
                .To((ViewModel model) => model.IsFavourite)
                .WithConversion(new BooleanToFavouriteImageConverter(), null)
                .WithConversion(new ImageToImageFromBundleConverter(), null)
                .Apply();
```

`IsFavourite` is `bool` property, which I want to convert to an image and after that set and the image as a bundle resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine the two `ValueConverters` in a new class.

Create a `BooleanToImageFromBundleConverter` that uses `BooleanToFavouriteImageConverter` and `ImageToImageFromBundleConverter`.

By doing this you use two converters only in a different way.

```
this.CreateBinding(UIImage)
                .For(i => i.Image)
                .To((ViewModel model) => model.IsFavourite)
                .WithConversion(new BooleanToImageFromBundleConverter(), null)
                .Apply();
```

---

At last if you want to extend this behaviour, lets say you got multiple types of images that you want to convert from boolean.

Try using the object parameter and create a statement that uses a different value `ValueConverter`.

```
.WithConversion(new BooleanToImageFromBundleConverter(), "Favorite")
```